# Call to multiple dispatch for async action generators

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

```js
//Action Generator
   export const userActionGenerator = () => {
        return function (dispatch) {
             axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
             .then((resp)=> {
                  //First Call to Dispatch 
                  dispatch({ type: 'GETUSER', payload: resp.data});
             })

        }       
            
   }


//Component
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';
  import { userActionGenerator} from '../store/appStore'

  class Users extends Component {
      render() {
           console.log(this.props)
           return (
              <div>
                Users Component
                <button onClick={this.props.getAllUsers}>
                Load Users</button>
                {this.props.data.map(item => {
                    return (
                        <div key={item.id}>
                            <h1>{item.name}</h1>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
              </div>
           )
       }
   }
   const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({data: state.users})
   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
            {
                getAllUsers: () => {
                    //Second Call to Dispatch
                    dispatch(userActionGenerator());
                }
            }
        )
   export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Users);
```

Calling "userActionGenerator" directly without "dispatch" is not giving any response, i could make it work by calling dispatch passing "userActionGenerator" function call.
But i fail to understand why do we need to call dispatch in the component again when the action generator has already invoked it.

Comment: How are you passing your ActionCreator i.e userActionGenerator to your Component?

Comment: yes, i am importing from another module. I updated the code to show the imports.

Comment: I didn't get one thing from your question. In your code, only once, the dispatch is getting called. why are you saying that you are calling it twice ?

Comment: @kumarmo2 if you see the code, i am again passing "userActionGenerator" to dispatch function in the bottom of my code inside "mapDispatchToProps".

Comment: You have to send it to redux with dispatch, otherwise, how is redux aware of it at all? When redux-thunk middleware is used and a function is dispatched, dispatch is then passed into the curried function to be called once an async operation is performed. You have to dispatch the function to redux in the first place though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action creator is actually a [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#whats-a-thunk).
When you `dispatch` it, the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) [middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware#middleware) will catch it and will invoke it.
Normal actions should be objects not functions, but `redux-thunk` [allows you to dispatch functions](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js#L3):

```
if (typeof action === 'function') {
  return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
}
```

When that function is invoked by `redux-thunk` it will have to dispatch a real action (an object), that's your second `dispatch`.

So this is the flow:

```
dispatch(userActionGenerator());
```

`redux-thunk` will catch this because `userActionGenerator` returns a function and not an object, it will invoke the returned function,
while passing it `(dispatch, getState, extraArgument)`:

```
return function (dispatch) {
   axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
   .then((resp)=> {
       //First Call to Dispatch 
       dispatch({ type: 'GETUSER', payload: resp.data});
     })
}
```

This returned function is dispatching an object, meaning `redux-thunk` will ignore it and will let the reducers (or other middlewares down the chain) handle this action.

Answer (score 0):

Using bindActionCreators is what you might need. [Here](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators) is official docs. Please go through it.

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

// Using bindActionCreators you don't need to use dispatch
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  // actions
  userActionGenerator,
  // action1,
  // action2,
  // ...
}, dispatch);
```

And in your actions file you have to write is as such.

```
const userActionGenerator = (...args) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(object1);
  dispatch(object2);
};
```